# How to print multiple integer array based on user Input?

Tags: java

I am creating a java program which prompts user for the number of items in an array (a non-negative integer), reads it, and saves it in an int variable. It then prompts user for the values of all the items and saves them in an int array. Afterwards, the program prints the content of the array in the form of [x1, x2, ... ,xn]. No user validation is required. The program was supposed to work out fine, however, when I tried to enter the multiple inputs for the user, there is something wrong with the output.

Instead of showing this:

```
Enter the number of items: 2
Enter the value of all items (separated by space): 88
Enter the value of all items (separated by space): 99
The values are: [88, 99]
```

The output becomes like this:

```
Enter the number of items: 2
Enter the value of all items (separated by space) : 88
Enter the value of all items (separated by space) : 99
The values are: [88]
The values are: [99]
```

Also, when I enter 0 for the number of items, the output was supposed to show this

```
Enter the number of items: 0
The values are: []
```

But my output shows this instead:

```
Enter the number of items: 0
```

It does not even show the brackets of the values when the number of items is 0. Attached below is my codings:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PrintArray{



public static void main(String[] args) {
 // Declare variables
      int numItems;
      int[] items;  // Declare array name, to be allocated after numItems is known


  // Prompt for a non-negative integer for the number of items;
  // and read the input as "int". No input validation.
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter the number of items: ");
  numItems = in.nextInt();


  // Allocate the array
  items = new int[numItems];

  // Prompt and read the items into the "int" array, if array length > 0
  if (items.length > 0) {

     for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        System.out.print("Enter the value of all items (separated by space) : ");
        items[i] = in.nextInt();

     }
  }

  // Print array contents, need to handle first item and subsequent items differently

  for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
     if (i == 0) {
        // Print the first item without a leading commas
        System.out.println("The values are: [" + items[i] + "]");
     } else {
        // Print the subsequent items with a leading commas
        System.out.println("The values are: [" + items[i] + "]");
     }

  }



  }
}
```

It would be good if someone can help me with that. Many thanks!

Comment: Just move `System.out.println("The values are: [" );` before your loop and `System.out.println("]");` after your loop. and only do the printing of `items[i]` inside your loop. edit: And you probably want to change it to `System.out.print` to have it all in the same line

Comment: Thanks for the info! My code works out fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the same array so it's printed many times. Try this for the last `for`:

```
String  values = ""
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {

    if (i == 0) {
        // Print the first item without a leading commas
        values = values + items[i];
     } else {
        // Print the subsequent items with a leading commas
        values = values + "," + items[i];
     }

System.out.println("The values are: [" + values + "]");
```

or you can also do like this which looks more readable:

```
String  values = "" + items[0];
for (int i = 1; i < items.length; ++i) {
        // Print the subsequent items with a leading commas
        values = values + "," + items[i];
     }

System.out.println("The values are: [" + values + "]");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information, my code works out fine :). However, I would like to know on how to add spacing between the outputs. For instance, instead of output displaying [3,2,4,5,6], I would like my output to be [3, 2, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: Just add the space after the coma like this: `values = values + ", " + items[i];`

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you're printing the whole sentence, instead you may append the array element to a String, for printing later.
Second problem is because array is empty, which makes loop condition false in the first iteration itself. Hence loop body is not executed.

You can try something like below.

```
String output = "[";
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    output += items[i] + ", ";
}

// remove last comma and space
output = output.substring(0, output.length() - 2);
output += "]";
System.out.println("The values are: " + output);
```